# Stand in Line Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im currently working thru the exercises on the javascript portion of the freecodecamp site and Im trying to understand why a particular method worked in solving it.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
   // Your code here
   arr.push(item);
   var firstItem = arr.shift(arr);
   return firstItem;  // Change this line
}
```

Im trying to understand why I had to create the variable firstItem in the first place? Is there another way I could of went about solving this exercise? If so please let me know how you went about solving it.

Comment: I recommend you read what shift does to an array

Comment: You don't have to create `firstItem`. You could just return `arr.shift()`. So `arr.push` adds an item to the end of the array, `shift` removes the item at the start of the array.

Comment: Yes, you could have done `return arr.shift(arr);`

Comment: If you are wanting us to comment as to how your code accomplishes whatever the requirements are for the exercise, you will need to state those requirements and/or provide a link to the exercise. However, that really is not what Stack Overflow is for. Reviewing functional code belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

I've also gone through this task as part of undertaking the Free Code Camp front end certification. For reference, this is the task: https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/stand-in-line

> Write a function `nextInLine` which takes an array (`arr`) and a number
>   (`item`) as arguments. Add the number to the end of the array, then
>   remove the first element of array. The nextInLine function should then
>   return the element that was removed.

While your solution delivers the desired outcome, it is possible to solve this task without declaring a variable (`firstItem` in your code). I've prepared and demo with description for you here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/xEYbgv

The crucial thing is to understand that:

> The shift() method **removes the first element** from an array **AND** **returns
>   that element**. This method changes the length of the array.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {

  // arr is now: [5,6,7,8,9]
  arr.push(item); // add 10 to the and of array
  // arr is now: [5,6,7,8,9,10]

  return arr.shift(); // remove first element of arr (5)
                      // and then return this first element (5),
                      // arr is now [6,7,8,9,10]
}

var testArr = [5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 10)); // 5
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr)); // After: [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: Alexander, I've just updated my answer with explanation of how returning `arr.shift()` delivers both: 1) removal of first element, AND 2) returning it from the function. Would you like me to add anything or does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The `.shift` function doesn't use any arguments. It just removes the first element of array one by one.
Here is the correct code.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var remove=arr.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return arr.shift(arr);`

with out declaring the variable to return

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item){
    arr.push(item); //this will add new element to the array, for our case, our array become [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    return arr.shift(arr); //the shift() method will remove the first //element and then return its value. 
//for our case, our new array becomes [11, 12, 13, 14 ,15], 10 will be returned as the value of the removed element
    return item; //will return the value of the item argument
    
};
 const myArray = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
 
 console.log(nextInLine(myArray, 15));
 //array.push(item) in this case will add 15 to the end of the array, and the new array will now be [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
 console.log(myArray);
 //arr.shift(arr) will take the new array[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] and remove the first element, which is "10", and then return it. Our new array will now be [11, 12, 13, 14, 15].
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).